# 4 circles one thread circling them

Tags: circles

Can somebody tell me how to measure the length of a thread which is wrapped around 4 circles the radius of each is `1m`. The four circles are touching but their centers don't form a square when they are connected. Can you please explain the steps and the laws you use when you measure the length of that thread an thanks.

Comment: So what DO the centers form? What do we know about these circles?

Comment: As long as the 4 circles are arranged like a ring (circle 1 touching 2, circle 2 touching 3, circle 3 touching 4 and circle 4 touching 1 again). Your thread will be composed of 4 line segments and 4 circular arcs. Convince yourself the length of each line segment is equal to the distance between the centers of two circles and the 4 circular arcs can be translated/rotated to combine into a single circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a figure to help with  achille hui's comment, which is what I was goin  write.  Note that DE and IH are the distance between the centers.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there a way to know the arc's measure just by the number of circles?

Comment: Not if you don't assume the centers form a specific polygon. For four circles you could have a square, where each arc is a.quarter circle, but you could also have a parallelogram with different angles.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification :)